# Is it possible to extend a BTRFS partition from within Windows?

Tags: linux, partitioning, btrfs, meego

I want to extend my BTRFS partition (and use up some free space on my NTFS) because I have run out of space for my Linux installation. How can I do this from within Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Not if they're on the same disk. For stability reasons you can't modify the partition table the partitioning program runs from. Just burn a [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/) disc.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind your file systems are separate from your partitions.  In order to expand a filesystem, you must first expand the partition and THEN expand the filesystem.  With shrinking it is just the opposite, you must shrink the filesystem and then shrink the partition.

Please see this [guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370598) for how to shrink your ntfs partition.

Comment: I shrunk my partition and now I have unallocated space. But how do I convert it to BTRFS now?

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea there is any Windows program support btrfs now. But in Linux, the task is really easy:

```
btrfs filesystem resize [+/-]"newsize" [gkm]|max "filesystem"
    Resize the file system. If 'max' is passed, the filesystem
    will occupe all available space on the device.
```

Comment: Why isn't the partition table updated, though? Or is it?